# Updating cells in pandas dataframe is changing the entire row instead?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe consists of DNA sequences, where each column contains 3 bases that represent codons. My goal is to update any codons that contain a certain string into gaps given a condition. Example condition, if any of the stop codons in my codon list appear in a column less than a certain %, edit those stop codons into gaps.

Example df:

```
            1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
species1    TAG GAC AGG TTA CTA TGG TCA TAA TTC CTG CTG TAA
species2    GTG GAC AGG TTG CGG TGG TCA TGA TTG CTG CTC TAA
species3    TTG GAC AGG TTA CTA TGG TCA TGA TTG CTG CTG TGA
species4    ACC AGC AGG TTC CTG TGC TCA GTT TTG CTG CTG TGA
species5    ATG GAC GGG GTA GTA CGG TCA GTT TTG CTC CTG TAG
species6    ATG GAC GGG ATA GTA CGG TCA GTG TTG CTC CTG TAG
species7    ATG GAC GGG ATA GTA CGG TCA GTT TTG CTC CTG CTG
species8    ATG GAC AGG TTA CGG TGG TCA GTT TTG CTG CTG CTG
species9    TTG GAC AGG TTA CTC TGG TCA GTG TTG CTG CTG CTG
species10   CCC GAC TAA C-C GTG GGT TGA TGG TTG CTG CTG CTG
```

My script to first keep track of columns with < 40% stops:

```
codon = ["TAG", "TAA", "TGA"]
df_track = df.loc[:, (df.isin(codon).sum()/len(df) <= frac1) & (df.isin(codon).sum() > 0)]
print(df_track)

            1   3   7   8   
species1    TAG AGG TCA TAA 
species2    GTG AGG TCA TGA 
species3    TTG AGG TCA TGA 
species4    ACC AGG TCA GTT 
species5    ATG GGG TCA GTT 
species6    ATG GGG TCA GTG 
species7    ATG GGG TCA GTT 
species8    ATG AGG TCA GTT 
species9    TTG AGG TCA GTG 
species10   CCC TAA TGA TGG
```

Then, after keeping that df_track for records, I need to edit those stops that appear < 40% in the original df:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if df.loc[:, (df.isin(codon).sum()/len(df) <= 0.4) & (df.isin(codon).sum() > 0)]:
        df[df[col] ==  (cod for cod in codon), col] = "---"
print(df)
```

This throws a warning:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What I expected after EDITING for stops:

```
            1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
species1    --- GAC AGG TTA CTA TGG TCA --- TTC CTG CTG TAA
species2    GTG GAC AGG TTG CGG TGG TCA --- TTG CTG CTC TAA
species3    TTG GAC AGG TTA CTA TGG TCA --- TTG CTG CTG TGA
species4    ACC AGC AGG TTC CTG TGC TCA GTT TTG CTG CTG TGA
species5    ATG GAC GGG GTA GTA CGG TCA GTT TTG CTC CTG TAG
species6    ATG GAC GGG ATA GTA CGG TCA GTG TTG CTC CTG TAG
species7    ATG GAC GGG ATA GTA CGG TCA GTT TTG CTC CTG CTG
species8    ATG GAC AGG TTA CGG TGG TCA GTT TTG CTG CTG CTG
species9    TTG GAC AGG TTA CTC TGG TCA GTG TTG CTG CTG CTG
species10   CCC GAC --- C-C GTG GGT --- TGG TTG CTG CTG CTG
```

Note, column 12 won't be edited or appear in df_tracks because in total, the stops appear in more than 40% of the species in this dataset, and so I would have a separate df tracker for those cases (basically if stops go over the % limit that entire column is tracked, then removed).

Comment: This really needs more clarification. What do you hope to achieve by `if df.loc[:, (df.isin(codon).sum()/len(df) <= 0.4) & (df.isin(codon).sum() > 0)]` ?

Comment: For example if one of the datasets I work with has 10 DNA samples in it, if "TGA", "TAA", or "TAG" appear in less than 40% of the samples in one column, I have to change those stop codons into gaps. My other goal is to then extract a different df where if they appear in over 40% of the samples, I have to remove that whole column. So in a sample of 10 species, if less than 4 of them have one of those stop codons, I need to edit it into gaps, preserving the rest of the column. The reason I also included the > 0 operation is because most columns don't have those stops and they should not show up.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53982947/edit). That way others can understand the Q&A if/when all comments are removed.

Comment: Okay did my best to edit it!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are changing the whole row with your code.
For example:

```
In[1]: df[2] == 'TGA'
Out[1]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: 2, dtype: bool
```

You will get a Series. Then, if you use this series to do DataFrame indexing, you will get all the rows where the Series is true.

```
In[2]: df[df[2] == 'TGA']
Out[2]: 
     1    2    3    4
0  ATG  TGA  CCC  CCC
```

If you use list to index you will get the same result.
In short, you can use the 'replace' method of pandas Dataframe. Like this:

```
df = df.replace(["TAG", "TAA", "TGA"], '---')
```

Comment: How does the replace method work if you need to include conditions, so that it only replaced those three codons in columns where they appear across all samples (rows) in a certain percentage? I do like this method though it seems more readable.

Comment: You need to specify the location .loc or .iloc if you want to add some contiones. I think @jpp 's answer is good enough.

Comment: Tried it all, it is still changing the entire row and as you said, treating it as a Series. Gotta figure this out...